# How do I encrypt an aws-cdk-lamdba environment variable using KMS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

```
export class CdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    const func = new lambda.Function(this, 'TestLambda', {
        runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_10_X,
        handler: 'index.handler',
        code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, 'resources\\lambda')),
        role: exeRole,
        environment: {
          "KEY_PHRASE": cipherText,//**I want to be able to encrypt this value using KMS**
        }
    });
  }
}
```

as the code snippet shows, I want to encrypt an environment variable **KEY_PHRASE** , is @aws-sdk/client-kms the one that I should look into? or is there a CDK lamdba native way of handling of this?

Answer (score 1):

Lambda encrypts environment variable at rest by default using a CMK that Lambda creates in your account. But you can create your own CMK and use this for encrypting environment variables.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-encryption